# Windows look-alike Linux/Unix

Tags: windows, gui, user-interface

The security/privacy focused distribution Tails features a camouflage-mode, that made it look like a Windows Desktop OS.

Is there a GUI/GUI-theme/GUI-extensions that makes a Linux/Unix desktop look like a Windows Desktop?

Comment: Are you asking about the cosmetic appearance or how your computer is "seen" by the rest of the world. In other words, do you want your Linux machine to be detected as a Windows machine?

Comment: The question is more on the appearance and user experience. However, making a Linux box appear as a Windows machine would also be an interesting question. So if you have an idea for this, feel free to post a follow-up question and post an answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Zorin OS is meant to look a lot like windows (or mac if you choose)

http://zorinos.com/

Comment: Never heard of that one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theme that makes Linux Mint look like Windows XP

http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2015/08/cinnxp-makes-cinnamon-look-like-windows-xp/